# Check for certain formatting in a word document

Tags: microsoft-word

Is there any way to automate the process of checking whether a word document has specific formatting or not? For example, checking multiple word documents on whether the header of those documents are formatted with Arial 10pt font or not.

Comment: How can you identify the header (other then by it's format)? e.g. is it the first line of text on the first page?

Comment: Yes. All of the documents will follow certain instructions. So, all the texts in those documents will be in a certain position.

Comment: You would need macros in a template, Normal or other, that would open the documents then check each header for the Font properties used on each paragraph. You'd also have to determine if the header paragraph had been direct formatted. If you are checking for compliance to a standard, it would be easier to just programmatically reapply the approved header style on all documents.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Rich. The problem is I don't have enough experience with macros. It would be very helpful if you can point to some references where I can start building my desired macro for word.

Comment: Just searching the phrase "Writing Word Macros" pulls up a lot of information.

Comment: You might want to post this in a forum for VBA questions. Although at this point you don't provide enough details so people can give you a specific answer (how exactly can you identify the header, how are the results suppose to be presented, etc.). Maybe it's more cost effective to find a VBA programmer to write the first version for you and continue from there yourself. Getting "into VBA" from scratch has some overhead you might avoid this way. But it all depends on your time and financial preference.